# Error printing Barcode - Code 39

Tags: css, barcode, code39

I'm having a problem while printing barcodes (Code 39 stadard). It's something that occurs intermittently.

-In Google Chrome:

It normally shows me the code, but when I see it on print view, it shows me a strange code instead of the original barcode it should show, like images below.

Before printing:

[image: Before printing]

After printing:

[image: After printing]

-In Internet Explorer:

The only difference is that, when I try printing it shows me only the codes, like image:

[image]

I'm using a CSS to custom the barcode, and I'm using text, not the image, to show the barcode.

Could anyone help me?

ps.:

The CSS I'm using for the barcode (I think it is a default):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'C39HrP24DhTtNormal';
    src: url('c39hrp24dhtt-webfont.eot');
    src: url('c39hrp24dhtt-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('c39hrp24dhtt-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('c39hrp24dhtt-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('c39hrp24dhtt-webfont.svg#C39HrP24DhTtNormal') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
    <head>
    <title>AAAAAAAAAA</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Controller/Configuratuion.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Library/JQuery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Library/AjaxHelper.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Library/Scripts.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Controller/PrintCapaloteClienteController.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            PrintCapaloteClienteController.Init();
        });
    </script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="css/BarCode3de9/stylesheet.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="css/Style.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body#Print
        {
            padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        }
        div#BarCodeContrainer
        {
            text-align: right;
        }
        div#HeaderContainer, .footer
        {
            border: solid 2px black;
        }
        div#MainContainer
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .leftText
        {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .rightText
        {
            text-align: right;
        }
        .centerText
        {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .header
        {
            text-align: left;
        }

        .header th
        {
            text-align: left;
            border-top: solid 1px black;
            border-bottom: solid 1px black;
        }

        .closeLeft
        {
            border-left: solid 1px black;
        }

        .closeRight
        {
            border-right: solid 1px black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="HeaderContainer">

    </div>
    <div id="MainContainer">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not using that stylesheet for `screen` and not also `print`? Sounds like an issue where the print is ignoring CSS.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It apears to be the Browser ignoring the CSS, but it happens once in a while.

Comment: I can confirm that webkit in general has at least two print-related bugs that can be font-specific. In one case, @media print rules get ignored and in the other, letter-spacing gets nasty. Maybe you're encountered one of those or another related one.